# When i process ajax request, i cant use other options

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am using AJAX in my application to fetch large amount data from database using PHP.
When i process ajax request, i cant able to use other option or cant click another menu. if i click another menu its loading till the ajax request completes.

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'api/get_data.php',
    dataType : 'json',
    beforeSend : function() {
        $("table#all_data tbody").html("<tr><td><img src='img/loader/loader.gif'> Fetching Data!. Please Wait...</td></tr>");
    },
    success : function(response) {
        if (response.success == true) {
            $("table#all_data tbody").html(response.data);
        } else {
            console.log(response.message);
        }
    },
    error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(jqXHR.responseText);
    }
});
```

Can anyone help to resolve this issue.

Comment: I believe your server method must be `asynchronous`.

Comment: What should i do. I'm missing anything?

Comment: Not sure how you do in `php`, as I don't come from that background, but you need to look into `asynchronous` methods in php, or post your method so that you can get help from other experts..

Comment: @Raj_King Try `async:true` and remove loader in before send request

Comment: its not a question of asyonchronous on the server side. And the ajax-request is non-blocking on the client as default, so my guess is that the request returns, and then whats executed on succes is whats blocking the thread. Materializing a big table into the DOM might be the casue